# what should I do to get the element from useEffect in function component of react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Now I am get the element with useEffect in React like this（this is just a minimal demo to demonstrate the issue）:

```
import React from 'react';

const App: React.FC = () => {

  React.useEffect(()=>{
    const resizeElement: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("demo");
    if(resizeElement == null){
      console.log("resizeElement is null");
    }
  },[]);

  return (
    <div id="demo">
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but sometimes the `resizeElement` is null. why the resizeElement is null? what should I do to get the element without failure? This is the full code in my production environment to do the resize, I put the `resizeRight` in the useEffect function:

```
const resizeRight = (resizeBarName: string, resizeArea: string) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let prevCursorOffset = -1;
      let resizing = false;
      const resizeElement: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById(resizeArea);
      const resizeBar: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById(resizeBarName);
      if (resizeBar !== null) {
        resizeBar.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
          resizing = true
        });
      }
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleResizeMenu);
      window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
        resizing = false
      });

      function handleResizeMenu(e: MouseEvent) {
        if (!resizing || resizeElement == null) {
          return
        }
        if (!divRef.current) {
          return;
        }
        const prjTreeWidth = divRef.current.offsetWidth;
        const { screenX } = e
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
        if (prevCursorOffset === -1) {
          prevCursorOffset = screenX
        } else if (Math.abs(prevCursorOffset - screenX) >= 5) {
          resizeElement.style.flex = `0 0 ${screenX - prjTreeWidth - 18}px`;
          resizeElement.style.maxWidth = "100vw";
          prevCursorOffset = screenX;
        }
      }
    }, 1500);
  }
```

I also tried like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const demoRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const resizeElement: HTMLElement | null = demoRef.current;

    if (resizeElement == null) {
      console.log("resizeElement is null");
    }
  }, [demoRef]);

  return (
    <div id="demo" ref={demoRef}>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The setTimeout in the full code makes it quite a bit different from the first example. Are you sure the component isn't unmounting in between the time when it rendered and when the timer goes off? Are you returning a cleanup function from your useEffect to teardown the timeout?

Comment: When you create a reference using `useRef`, what do you need `useEffect` for?

Answer (score 0):

The oracle had something to say about your problem:

It seems you're encountering an issue with accessing an element in React using useEffect. The reason resizeElement is sometimes null may be related to the timing of the code execution in relation to the component's lifecycle.

The problem here is that the code inside useEffect may run before the component is fully rendered and the element with the ID "demo" is created in the DOM. To address this issue, you can use refs in React to ensure that the element already exists before trying to access it. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const demoRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Use the current property of the ref to access the DOM element
    const resizeElement: HTMLElement | null = demoRef.current;

    if (resizeElement == null) {
      console.log("resizeElement is null");
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="demo" ref={demoRef}>
      {/* Your component content goes here */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In this example, demoRef is a ref associated with the element with the ID "demo". This ensures that the ref is updated after the component is rendered, and you can access the element using demoRef.current in the useEffect. This should resolve the issue of resizeElement being null in certain cases.

The oracle knows well, I agree with him.

Comment: `The problem here is that the code inside useEffect may run before the component is fully rendered` How would this happen?

Comment: I have tried what you said. This could not work. @Pedro Rodrigues